# How to Call a WebService without using WebReference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, json.net, webmethod

I want to know if there is someone who had use a Class to Call a WebService, this WS receives an integer after the organizational references and responds into a json file,

Actually my issue is to call the webservice without using a webreference, and read the json file and parse it into a dictionary ,

I appreciate your help

Best Regards, i let you my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using Dimex.ChangeSAP.Core.Utilities;

namespace Dimex.ChangeSAP.Core.Utilities
{
    class ConsumirWebService
    {
        public void ConsumirWS()
        {

            Dimex.ChangeSAP.Core.Entities.Seguridad.Usuario users = new Dimex.ChangeSAP.Core.Entities.Seguridad.Usuario();
            int idUsuaro = users.IdUsuario;

            try
            {

                System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.8.97/PassportPruebas/api/partners?enterprise_system_id=1&organizational_reference=" + idUsuaro);
                //req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyString, true);
                //Add these, as we're doing a POST
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.Method = "POST";
                //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. 
                //Post'ed Faked Forms should be name=value&
                string postData = "OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=90BA&INPUT_DATA=" + sendXML;
                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
                req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
                os.Close();
                System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                if (resp == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                System.IO.StreamReader sr =
                      new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

                string respuesta = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                return respuesta;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
                //throw or return an appropriate response/exception
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: google has a lot of results using your exact title

Comment: no way? are you sure ? i had hours looking for answers, but actually i resolved by my self thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a proxy class using wsdl utility or svcutil in visualstudiocommand prompt enter command wsdl.exe /out:[path and name of the file] /language:CS

Answer (score 2):

Well Actually here is my code for anyone with this kind of issue too,

```
        public static string LlamarWebService(string url)
        {

            try
            {
                System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

                req.ContentType = "application/json";
                req.Method = "GET";

                System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                if (resp == null) return null;
                System.IO.StreamReader sr =
                      new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

                string respuesta = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                return respuesta;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
                // return "";
                //throw or return an appropriate response/exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your catch if you're just going to rethrow it? What about cleaning up resources like req and resp and sr? using() is your friend!